# Let R = Z/4Z = {0, 1, 2, 3}. Find elements of R[x] which are neither units nor zero divisors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that units are elements that are congruent to 1 modulo 4 when multiplied to some element in Z/4Z. I know that zero divisors are elements that are congruent to 0 modulo 4 when multiplied to some element in Z/4Z. How can there be a polynomial that results in a number that is neither a unit nor a zero divisor in this set? 0 and 2 are zero divisors and 1 and 3 are units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(2x+1)^2=4x^2+4x+1\equiv 1$ so that $2x+1$ is a unit.

$2\cdot(2x)=4x\equiv 0$ so $2x$ is a zero divisor.

Is $x$ a unit, or a zero divisor, or something else?